# Upper-bounding determinacy

Tags: set-theory, lo.logic, descriptive-set-theory, determinacy

While the converse of Borel determinacy ("If a set of reals is determined, then it is Borel") is boringly disprovable, I'm curious if there is a sense in which something like it is consistent. Let $\mathsf{Opt}$ be the statement "For every non-Borel set $A$, the smallest $\sigma$-algebra containing $A$ and all the open sets and closed under continuous preimages contains a non-determined set."

> **Question 1**: Is $\mathsf{ZFC+Opt}$ consistent?

We can of course vary this basic idea. For example, let $\mathsf{Opt_{proj}}$ be the statement "For every non-projective set $A$, the smallest $\sigma$-algebra containing $A$ and the open sets and closed under continuous preimages and continuous images contains a non-determined set." The analgous question then is the following:

> **Question 2**: Is $\mathsf{ZFC+PD+Opt_{proj}}$ consistent (relative to large cardinals)?

Here $\mathsf{PD}$ is needed to avoid a trivial positive answer.

Generally, I'm curious whether there is any reasonable way to *upper*-bound the extent of determinacy. Certainly even in question $1$ there is some flexibility in forming the relevatn $\sigma$-algebra associated to a set of reals, and it's totally plausible to me that I've guessed incorrectly there.

Comment: Why are you so focused on $\sigma$-algebras?  The class of determined sets, after all, is not necessarily even an algebra, let alone a $\sigma$-algebra.

Comment: @JoelDavidHamkins That's sort of the point! I'm basically asking whether it's consistent that, if $A$ is "topologically complicated," there is some set "built simply from $A$" which is undetermined. To me, countable Boolean combinations are part of the "simple" toolbox, and the fact that the determined sets aren't a $\sigma$-algebra amounts to saying that countable Boolean combinations are a potentially useful tool in this context.

Comment: OK, but my point is that the same idea could be made about algebra, instead of $\sigma$-algebra.

Comment: @JoelDavidHamkins Yes, but restricting the set of tools allowable makes it harder to prove the consistency result in question. I've tried to make a positive answer to Q1 (and to a lesser extent Q2) as plausible as possible.

Comment: (Late @JoelDavidHamkins:) Additionally I believe at least $\mathsf{Opt}$ has a nice computational meaning: unless I'm missing something, it's equivalent to "For every non-Borel $A$ there is some $B\le_KA,{}^2E$ which is undetermined" *(where $\le_K$ is Kleene reducibility, i.e. higher-type reducibility allowing real parameters, and ${}^2E$ is the jump functional)*. This is to my mind a reasonably faithful precisiation of "Every non-Borel set computes an undetermined game." The $\sigma$-algebra bit corresponds to allowing ${}^2E$ as an auxiliary oracle, which I think is natural in this setting.